# TL494 error amplifier pin maximum voltage input

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, feedback, error-amplifier, tl494

I'm designing a 60V SMPD for my CNC milling machine using a TL494.

I've have successfully driven the gate drive transformer which can in turn drive the MOSFETs.  I am able to get 60 up to 70V output from the transformer. I'll do rectification and filtering.

I'm doing it step by step and it is voltage regulation time.

I have read about error amplifiers in the datasheet and I came across this circuit where 4.92V is given to pin 1 of the TL494 which is the non-inverting pin.

1. What is the maximum voltage that you can give to the error amplifier input pins?
2. Can you give me a hint on how to regulate 60V DC?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM in the initial picture schematic : short between pins C1 and C2.

Replaced 2 secondaries by one. Bridge rectifier used. Same behavior.

[image]

[image]

Q1 - [This note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva001e/slva001e.pdf?ts=1632490137000&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) , figure 12 tell you the input voltage you can use ("input" 0 -> 20 mV) for amplifier (so around Vref = 5 V). See figure 11 for properly biasing techniques ...

Q2 - You should use simulator http://www.spectrum-soft.com/index.shtm for testing your SMPS controller. The model used for TL494 seems quite good and the above schematic can be simulated without problems and is a good starting point. Adapt the resistors used for "measuring" voltage (22k and 4k7 ->
~ 5 V on pin 1) and adapt also transformer ratio. Next, you can define your own specs.